# 404 When Trying to Access Script that's Installed Next to EE

Tags: 404

I have a script installed in the root domain where EE is also installed, but when I try to access it this EE option is triggered:

"404 Page: Determines which template should be displayed when someone tries to access an invalid URL. Note: If you choose 'None', your default channel will be shown when an invalid URL is requested."

My question: is there a way to install scripts next to EE and have them work?

P.S. I have strict URLs disabled

The script is an affiliate link redirect and management script, I call at the URL mydomain.com/scriptfoldername/ or mydomain.com/scriptfoldername/file.php, both give me the 404.

The contents of my .htaccess: http://codetidy.com/5412/

Comment: Not enough information: what sort of script, what URL are you calling it at, do you have any template groups named the same, do you have any .htaccess rewriting rules that might be affecting it?

Comment: Just added that info to my original post, I don't have a template group named the same.

Comment: Could you try renaming / disabling your .htaccess and see if the link to the script works? That's a quick way to isolate the problem.

Comment: When you say 'script' is this a regular PHP file? What does it do and how are you trying to access it? From your templates?

Comment: Do you have a template group called scriptfoldername?